# SQL - Not able to locate/see currently executing blocking query in master db sysprocess

Tags: sql-server

I have created scenario where created blocking transaction and query in master.dbo.sysprocesses table (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses where blocked <> 0) to see blocked and blocking query but I am not able to see.
One more thing is i can see when i run it on my local sql server but on one of the preprod server I could not see.

help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
--Blocking transaction--
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  update Person set status_id=1 where person_id=2584968
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:05';
  COMMIT
END;

--Blocked query--

select * from Person where person_id=2584968
```

Comment: Do you have `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission on the server?

Comment: Not related to your problem but `sysprocesses` is a deprecated view that should not be used. Instead, use `sys.dm_exec_requests`.

Comment: nope but i tried with this USE MASTER
GO
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO user_name

Comment: @DanGuzman - using sys.dm_exec_requests table, i can not see blocked column which is there in sysprocesses, please suggest which will be having following columns spid, waittime, loginname, programname etc

Comment: @RajeshShegokar, the `sys.dm_exec_request` column names for some of that information are `blocked_session_id`, `session_id`, `wait_time`. Join to `sys.dm_exec_sessions` on `session_id` to  to get `program_name`, `loging_name`, etc.

Comment: @Dan Guzman - Sure let me try this.

Comment: @DanGuzman - Db server moved to cloud and restricted access to master or any system sp and table but provided with only necessary data (wrapper System SP) including what i want but i can not deal with that resultset as i am not sure table structure and store

Comment: @RajeshShegokar, if you don't have the needed permissions, there isn't much you can do but ask your DBA either grant you `VIEW SERVER STATE` or have them run the queries for you.

Comment: @DanGuzman   - sure let me get in touch with them thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To see all active connections you must have `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission on the server, otherwise you can only see the your current session (the session from where you will be running the dbo.sysprocesses query).

You can use the following command to grant the neccesary permission.

```
USE master;  
GO
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [MyUser];  
GO
```

Comment: it says can not find user or you dont have permission message

Comment: @RajeshShegokar Well you need to use your user `[MyUser]` was an example.

Comment: yeah i replaced [MyUser] with my userid with [] and without but getting error msg below

Comment: yeah i replaced [MyUser] with my userid with [] and without but getting error msg below Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the login 'username', because it does not exist or you do not have permission